# SVG with Angular directive : bad performances

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, svg

Its the first time I'm asking something here but i'm totally stuck.
I'm creating an interactive svg map with Angular. It works fine with D3 but I would like to use Angular, with its directives and templates.

Currently, I managed to have the map show up on screen and manipulate it, but the performances are awful.
 I know that I must filter my datas but i don't know where : is it on the controller, or the directive's link, or the API ? I don't know.

Note that I'm still a noob with Angular (hardly a month), even with code since I started to learn it 3 months ago. So, you will certainly read some silly stuff here.

**Anyway, my question is : what I am supposed to do to replace my complex ng-hide by a simple ng-if (i want to remove path depending on the year input).**

So, I'm retrieving a JSON list of path from my API.

**myjson :**
    [  { "land_name" : "landa", "path" : "...", "born" : 5000, end : 5152}
    { "land_name" : "landi", "path" : "...", "born" : 1200, end : 7100}
    { "land_name" : "lando", "path" : "...", "born" : 100, end : 4000} ]

**my api (node + mongoose):**

```
// get all the lands (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/landapi)
.get(function(req, res) {
    landapi.find(function(err, docs) {
        if (err)
        res.send(err);
  res.json(docs);
});
});
```

***angular :***

**my factory :**

```
.factory('landDataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/landapi')
    .success(function(data) {
      return data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      return err;
    });
```

**my controller :**

```
  .controller('testCtrl',  function($scope, landDataFactory) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.paysList = [];

  vm.year = ''; (==> ng-model in the template)

  landDataFactory.success(function(data) {
    vm.land = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.land.length; i++) {
      vm.LandList.push(vm.land[i]);
    }
  });
```

**my directive :**

```
.directive('dynamicMap', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace : true,
    scope: {
      datapath : '=',
      year : '='
    },
    templateUrl : './modules/dynamicmap.tpl.html',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

    }
  };
```

**my template :**

```
<div>
  <div class="year">
    <input ng-model="year" type="number" step="50" class="inputDate col-xs-2 form-control" placeholder="date""> <br/>
  </div>
  <svg class="Map">
    <g class="drawLand"  ng-repeat="data in datapath">
      <path ng-hide="year == NULL || data.born > year || data.end < year" ng-attr-d="{{ data.path }}" id="{{ data.id_land }}"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**my directive when i'm calling it :**

```
<dynamic-map datapath="vm.paysList" year="vm.year"></dynamic-map>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which performance part you are complaining from. Is it the render time on startup or when you scroll/pan the map. Or when the scope value changes

Comment: 2nd et 3rd, since when I scroll the scope value changes

Answer (score 0):

I am barely qualified to comment since I only played with Angular for about 2 days, but in that brief period, I found that it is extremely easy to run into performance issues if you have even medium sized data sets. From what I understand, you should try very hard to limit how many two way data bindings you create. Since your code has an ng-repeat, you should, if possible, look at making the bindings inside of the repeat one way by replacing `{data:path}` with `{::data.path}`.

My real advise though is to not use angular. From what I can tell, Angular 1.0 is a dead end since it will soon be eclipsed with Angular 2.0. In addition the entire philosophy of Angular seems built around the idea of *"Look how nice this syntax is! HTML and javascript have never been easier!"*, to *"Oh, you want to make a real app? Well here's some ugly hacks to make it perform, and by the way, don't you understand the difference between a directive and a factory-directive and a directive-factory? And how could you not know that every tag has different scoping rules..."*.

In short, wait for Anuglar 2.0 or look for something else. I went with react.js and so far find it to lighter weight and more intuitive and a better for long run productivity.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably follow that advice. But for now, I will keep trying for a while..